# Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid query. You must not call startAt() or startAfter() before calling orderBy()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add functionality to fetch the next 4 comments but when I click on the `Load more comments` button, it throws this error message.

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid query. You must not call startAt() or startAfter() before calling orderBy().

Anyone, please help me with this.

SolutionComments.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection"

import Comment from "./Comment"
import CommentForm from "./CommentForm"

const SolutionComments = () => {
  const [activeComment, setActiveComment] = useState(null)
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { documents, fetchMore } = useCollection(`solutions/${id}/comments`, null, 4, [
    "createdAt",
    "desc",
  ])

  const fetchMoreComments = () => {
    fetchMore(documents[documents.length - 1])
  }

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <CommentForm docID={id} />
      <div>
        {documents &&
          documents.map((comment) => (
            <Comment
              key={comment.id}
              comment={comment}
              replies={comment.replies}
              activeComment={activeComment}
              setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={fetchMoreComments} className="text-white bg-purple-500">
        Load More Comments!
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SolutionComments
```

useCollection hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
// firebase import
import {
  collection,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  query,
  startAfter,
  where,
} from "firebase/firestore"

import { db } from "../firebase/config"

export const useCollection = (c, _q, _l, _o) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  // if we don't use a ref --> infinite loop in useEffect
  // _query is an array and is "different" on every function call
  const q = useRef(_q).current
  const o = useRef(_o).current
  let ref = collection(db, c)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (q) {
      ref = query(ref, where(...q))
    }
    if (o) {
      ref = query(ref, orderBy(...o))
    }
    if (_l) {
      ref = query(ref, limit(_l))
    }

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return unsubscribe
  }, [c, q, _l, o, isLoading])

  // I'm using this function to fetch next 4 comments including the previous ones.
  const fetchMore = (doc) => {
    ref = query(ref, orderBy(...o), startAfter(doc), limit(_l))
    onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )
      // update state
      console.log(results)
      setDocuments([...documents, results])
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })
  }

  return { documents, fetchMore, error, isLoading }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `onSnapshot()` to start your query.  Since you are doing paging, it is likely you want to use `getDocs()` instead.

At the very least, you want to be sure to shut down your previous listener for `onSnapshot()` before starting a new one.  But it is rarely all that useful/correct to use an `onSnapshot()` with paging.  Things get hairy-complicated under that approach.

Comment: After using getDocs(), it's working fine. Thanks for your help